# oauth for html5 enabled devices

Tags: html, mobile, cookies, oauth

I'm building a webapp specifically for iOS and Android devices which requires user to sign in with their Facebook or Twitter accounts.  I have it setup so that initially they're redirected to the appropriate login page and upon successful completion my provided calllback url is triggered.

Because I want to implement a single sign on, I will be storing on the user's device the access token that I received so they can easily access the webapp without having to sign in again next time.

My question is this: is it better to store it as an html4 cookie from the server side? Or is it better to insert it as a hidden input in the home page and have javascript on the client grab it and store it with the new local/sessionStorage? And if the latter, which type of storage would be better for this type of data that I would like to save?

Comment: You are aware that access tokens expire after a couple hours, right?

Comment: Actually it depends on the provider. FB, yes, but Twitter no. Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought it was actually just FB that expired after a couple hours. Others typically won't expire unless the user revokes the app.